# How can I add other product link with shopify variant

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I like to add a product link with a color variant in Shopify.

Can you please guide me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about linking to a product page, rather than a [permalink](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Cart-Use-permalinks-to-pre-load-the-cart/td-p/613702).

If that assumption is right it is possible, but will depend on the theme code in place. For example you may be able to link to a product with a url like this:

```
/products/the-product-handle?variant=123456789
```

The number at the end is the variant ID. If your theme is setup in the right way it would grab the variant id and make sure the correct variant is selected, ready to add to the cart. Not all themes do this however so it could be something you need to build in.